Possible to have org-mode task repeat to a default time of day, and not its currently scheduled time?
I have many repeating tasks which are normally scheduled for a specific time of the day.
But sometimes I have a scheduling conflict and have to temporarily change the time of one of these tasks.
The problem is that when I later mark the task as "DONE", the task will repeat to the time I temporarily set for that day, instead of the tasks usual time. I don't always remember to manually revert each rescheduled task's time, resulting in errors in my schedule.
For example, say I normally eat lunch at noon:
* Eat lunch
SCHEDULED: <2024-05-13 12:00 ++1d>

Then one day, I have a meeting at noon, and have to postpone my lunch to 1pm:
* Eat lunch
SCHEDULED: <2024-05-13 13:00 ++1d>

If I just mark lunch as DONE, it will be scheduled for 1pm the next day:
* Eat lunch
SCHEDULED: <2024-05-14 13:00 ++1d>

But lunch is usually at noon, so I would like it to instead be:
* Eat lunch
SCHEDULED: <2024-05-13 12:00 ++1d>


Given that Org mode files are just text, whatever time you have in the buffer currently is going to be the time that the repeat is going to use. It isn't as if there is some memory or history somewhere that Org mode consults: it's the current contents of the buffer.

You can perhaps write a function that checks for "well-known" events and make sure that the time is "correct", sort of a linter for your Org agenda files.

Just mark the original as complete and capture a new instance of lunch just for today. It takes about the same amount of time to reschedule it anyway.
